# how to insert null date into access

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

i want to insert null date into access database if user payment choose as cash then cheque date should be insert as empty for this im using masked textbox , i use debugger also but every time debugger going else condition and for that its giving me data mismatch exception here is im giving my insert code

```
string bank = txtbankname.Text;
            bank = "";
            string cheque = txtchequeno.Text;
            cheque = "";


            string billno = txtbillno.Text;
            billno = "";


            string codecreate = txtcodecreator.Text;
            codecreate = "";

            string connetionString = null;
            connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            cnn.ConnectionString = connetionString;

            string SqlString = "Insert Into Billing([FormNo],[Date],[TruckNo],[Office_Code],[Party_Code],[Party_Code1],[Location],[Supplier],[Item],[Invoice_no],[Invoice_date],[Package],[Weight],[Invest_Amount],[Percentage],[Amount],[Total_Amount],[Payment_Amount],[Payment_Type],[Bank_Name],[Cheque_No],[Cheque_Date],[Bill_No],[Bill_Date],[Code_Create]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, cnn))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormNo", txtformno.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtdate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TruckNo", txttruck.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Office_Code", txtofficecode.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Party_Code", txtpartycode.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Party_Code1", txtpartycode1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", txtlocation.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", txtsupplier.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", txtitem.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Invoice_no", txtinvoice.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Invoice_date", DateTime.Parse(txtmaskinvoice.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Package", txtpackage.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", txtwieght.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Invest_Amount", Convert.ToDouble(txtinvestamount.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percentage", txtpercentage.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", Convert.ToDouble(txtamount.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Amount", Convert.ToDouble(txttotalamount.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment_Amount", Convert.ToDouble(txtpaymentamount.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment_Type", txtpaymenttype.Text);
                if (txtbankname.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bank_Name", bank);

                }

                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bank_Name", txtbankname.Text);
                }


                if (txtchequeno.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_No", cheque);
                }
                else
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_No", txtchequeno.Text);
                }


                DateTime chequeDate;
                var value = (object)DBNull.Value;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskchequedate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",null,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out chequeDate))
                {



                    value = chequeDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value);  

                }
                else
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date",(txtmaskchequedate.Text));  

                }

                if (txtbillno.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_No", billno);

                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_No", txtbillno.Text);


                }

                DateTime BillDate;
                var value1 = (object)DBNull.Value;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskbilldate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out BillDate))
                {



                    value1 = BillDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_Date", value1);

                }
                else
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_Date", (txtmaskbilldate.Text));

                }



                if (txtcodecreator.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Create", codecreate);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_Create", txtcodecreator.Text.ToString());
                }



                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully", "Data Inserted ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check in if there is a valid date entered in your textbox control. But if it is not you use the content of the textbox as parameter value anyway. - This certainly is not right.

As `value` is initialized to DBNull, you can add the parameter in any case and don't need the else part of your code at all. 
Change your code:

```
DateTime chequeDate;
var value = (object)DBNull.Value;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskchequedate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",null,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out chequeDate))
{
    value = chequeDate;
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value);
```

The exact same problem with adding the text from textbox even though it is invalid, exists for the `@Bill_Date` parameter. Rewrite the code for that parameter according to my sample as well.

Comment: still same exception i got i change code like this  DateTime chequeDate;
                var value = (object)DBNull.Value;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskchequedate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out chequeDate))
                {
                    value = chequeDate;
                }

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value); i put debugger also for this but debugger go cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value); this line only if masked textbox empty

Comment: I tested code in the answer. It works in both cases. I think you should step through your code with the debugger. The line with ...Parameters.AddWithValue... should be always executed.

Comment: thank you for reply, i also use debugger its going in always in cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value);  either im enter date value or not if i enter date value DATA INSERT SUCCESSFULLY but if im not its give me exception

Comment: i set shortdate format in access table and then try to run your code, its running perfectly my dear friend , thank you very very much for your effort and help!!