# how to add null date into access database using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

i want to insert null date into access database, if user select payment option as cash then cheque_date value should automatically enter as null if user not provide bill then bill_date should be enter as null in database iam trying to do this but Data type mismatch in criteria expression exception is coming for bill|_date and cheque_date im using masked textbox and for chequeno. and bill no. im using textbox(checkno and billno. its can be store as empty only problem is storing null date into accessc database)

```
if (txtchequeno.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_No", cheque);
                }
                else
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_No", txtchequeno.Text);
                }





            DateTime chequeDate;
            var value = (object)DBNull.Value;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskchequedate.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out chequeDate))
            {
                value = chequeDate;
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value);  

 if (txtbillno.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_No", billno);

                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_No", txtbillno.Text);


                }


              DateTime billdate;
            var value1 = (object)DBNull.Value;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskbilldate.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out billdate))
            {
                value1 = billdate;
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bill_Date", value1);
```

here im change my code but still same error showing me Data type mismatch expression not getting still how to solve

Comment: Are you looking for [DBNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)? Btw. your code seems weird. For example if "Cheque_Date" really is a `Date` column, you're probably not allowed to feed it the contents of `txtmaskchequedate.Text`, which is a `string`, not a `DateTime`.

Comment: yes dbnull.value only but if user not enter anything then value should be null

Comment: i change my code if (DateTime.Parse(txtmaskchequedate.Text)==null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", DBNull.Value);
                  
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", txtmaskchequedate.Text);
                } but its give me String was not recognized as a valid DateTime exception

Comment: That exception is thrown, because the content of `txtmaskchequedate.Text` cannot be parsed to a `DateTime`. Btw. `DateTime.Parse` will never return `null`. See [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) for how to *try to parse* a `string` that might represent a `DateTime`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert null date into access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566423/how-to-insert-null-date-into-access)

Comment: @Gustav: actually last 5 days im trying to get solution that's why i make another post im frustrated by doing various type of code  of inserting null date into database but im failed that's why i create another post hope someone help me out

Comment: @Atul - Well, that's generally not the way to go... Also, what's wrong with the approach described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36567161/1336590 ? That's more or less the way I'd do it.

Comment: @Corak: i written that code also but still its giving me Data type mismatch in criteria expression execption

Comment: @Corak :   DateTime chequeDate;
                var value = (object)DBNull.Value;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskchequedate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out chequeDate))
                {
                    value = chequeDate;
                }
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value);  
for bill_date also write same like code but still giving me above exception

Comment: @Corak : if i fill all value including this cheque_date and bill_date data inserted successfully but if i miss this tow field its giving me  Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: @Corak : sorry my freind  for trouble but DateTime chequeDate;
             DateTime chequeDate;
                    var value = (object)DBNull.Value;
                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskchequedate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out chequeDate))
                    {
                        value = chequeDate;
                    }


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value);

perfectly work ..

Answer (score 0):

i set format : shortdate for cheque_date field in access database and here executed following code which is executed successfully either field having value or not(thank you @phils and @corak)

```
DateTime chequeDate;
                    var value = (object)DBNull.Value;
                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtmaskchequedate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out chequeDate))
                    {
                        value = chequeDate;
                    }


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cheque_Date", value);
```